# TEM diffraction analysis- imaging artifact or distorted crystal structure

Tags: electrons, diffraction, crystals

I've got some "nanobeam" diffraction data from TEM (transmission electron microscope). Analysis is a challenging because I forgot the golden rule... I didn't measure a "standard".

Hence, I don't know if my measurements are off because I am a novice operator (and could have introduced astigmatism etc) or if my specimen's structure is slightly different from the *known* structure in the databases.
As shown in this first image- there is a troubling discrepancy from the expected pattern:

[image]

But if I discard my space group and distort the unit cell (originally tetragonal) a little bit, pushing the base to 5 degrees out of square (to correspond with angles measured from data)... things start to line up better:

[image]

My question is: Which explanation is more likely?

*I am using Crystalmaker for predictions and Digital Micrograph for measurement. 
 Overlaid images are oriented by eye, and scaled to 1 -1 0 spot*

Comment: The structure in question is known to have a tetragonal unit cell, a square bottomed rectangle;  I've adjusted it so the base of the unit cell is slightly out-of-square.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Diffraction in TEM is prone to issues, particularly since they are inherently thin films with all that entails. As one example, contemplate how much curl the sample would need to replicate your distortions.

Comment: Thank you Jon!  I have considered specimen curl/bend/tilt as a source for error, but not in enough depth to say I have contemplated it.  It is definitely a possibility- the sample itself is particles that look like a miniature version of the breakfast cereal Corn Flakes.  Can you refer me to a source that covers how it could cause translation of the diffraction spots?  All I have found is coverage of is brightness of spots changing with curl/tilt.